# Citrix Access Management Console - How to add new user

Tags: citrix

Good Day

I have a hosted application inside the Citrix Presentation Server installed on a Windows Server edition.

My question is: How do I add a new user?

Answer (score 0):

Link for Citrix Presentation Server 4.5:

[Citrix Presentation Server 4.5 Administrator Guide](http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/12606-102-16435/Administrators_Guide.pdf)

Comment: thank you, but I can't find anything on how to add a new user...just how to add new admin users to access the console

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the published app, select Application Properties, browse the Users page and add the user.

Also this isn't a programming question. You should ask these types of questions on Server Fault instead.